# jQuery beginner selection

Tags: jquery

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="first-div">
    <p><a>click this</a></p>
</div>
<br />
<div class="second">
    <p>show this</p>
</div>
```

I hide `.second` on document load. When I click the only anchor, I want to select the div with class `second`, tried everything but still no luck.

This is my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".second").hide()
    $("a").click(function(e) {
        $(this).parent().parent().next(".second").toggle()
    });
});
```

Also, I have several of those divs loaded dynamically in PHP.

Comment: You mean show, not select

Comment: Please post the code you tried.

Comment: Also, I would use an ID rather than a class to uniquely identify an element. Much faster, and designed for that.

Comment: Have you stepped through this in your browser's JS debugger to see what the heck `$(this).parent().parent().next(".second")` actually selects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change,

```
$(this).parent().parent().next(".second").toggle()
```

to

```
$(this).parent().parent().nextAll(".second").toggle()
```

`next` element is not `.second` but `br`.

Also,

`$(this).closest('.first-div').nextAll(".second").toggle()` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `hide()` and `show()`

For your link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="ShowIt()">Show</a>
```

And in your code:

```
function ShowIt() {
    $('.second').show()
}
```